# As to the progress bar videojs player to make draggable slider?

Tags: slider, progress-bar, video.js

As to the progress bar videojs player to make draggable slider? like here http://take.ms/2m2cW

Answer (score -1):

```
var down = false;

    me.controlBar.progressControl.on('mousedown', function() { down = true; });

    me.controlBar.progressControl.on('mouseup', function() { down = false;  });

    me.controlBar.progressControl.on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if(down) {
            console.log(this.seekBar.update());
        }
    });
```